# MAUI Razor app software keyboard overlaps form

Tags: maui, maui-blazor

I have application with list and form at the bottom. When I tap on entry keyboard is overlapping my form. I added

```
On<Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
```

to App class - it makes my content being resized, but still I have to scrolldown manually. Is there any possibility to make my content scroll after keyboard show? I tried to scroll by JS to the last element but no success.
[image] [image][image]

EDIT
I added even on focus where I send message and receive it in MainPage.cs and then call ScrollToAsync(0,800,true); on ScrollView. It is working, but it doesn't make any sense to code focus event on every input in my application

Comment: Have you tried [Scroll programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/scrollview?view=net-maui-8.0#scroll-programmatically)  in ScrollView?

Comment: I tried and changed the description. It works, but doesn't make any sense :)

Comment: Oh, got it. I think you may raise a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).